# Errors on line *asp appear on *designer.cs in monodevelop

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono, monodevelop

[image: wrong file with error]

Monodevelop references the error on the expected line number but in the *.designer.cs file instead of the *aspx file.

I'm trying to edit/compile a asp.net project that coworkers developed in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm using

> MonoDevelop Version 4.1.7 Installation UUID:
>   1fe355a8-20c0-443a-a284-93926d1ae3be Runtime:     Mono 3.2.3 (tarball Sun
>   Sep 22 20:38:43 UTC 2013) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.21 theme: Adwaita     GTK#
>   (2.12.0.0)
>
> Build Information Git revision:
>   e8fdedb643e429aeeb1308c56cee67e098234f0c Build date: 2013-10-23
>   19:41:47+0000
>
> Operating System Linux Linux reese-loeff114 3.11.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP
>   PREEMPT Sat Oct 5 21:22:51 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Packages:

```
» ls packages
AjaxControlToolkit.7.1005  Ext.NET.Utilities.2.3.0             Google.GData.Extensions.2.2.0.0       Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8
AjaxMin.4.97.4951.28483    Google.GData.AccessControl.2.2.0.0  HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.6                 repositories.config
AjaxMin.5.2.5021.15814     Google.GData.Calendar.2.2.0.0       Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0  Transformer.NET.2.1.1
Ext.NET.2.3.1              Google.GData.Client.2.2.0.0         Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.8                 WebActivatorEx.2.0.3
```

> Error: The tag type 'asptextbox' has not been registered.

is a case issue. It should be "asp:TextBox".

Comment: I am finding the exact same problem. Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: For other reasons, I started a new project and imported files from the original project one by one. This repaired a lot of bizarre functionality, including the wrong file error messages.

Comment: I am having this issue as well, importing the files one by one is not an option in this case.